# 0 element in image collection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat

```
var roi = 
/* color: #d63000 */
/* displayProperties: [
  {
    "type": "rectangle"
  }
] */
ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[112.01637668750301, 30.256437069990916],
      [112.01637668750301, 29.3316436760148],
      [113.72749729297176, 29.3316436760148],
      [113.72749729297176, 30.256437069990916]]], null, false);
// remove cloud for Landsat 4, 5 and 7
  var rmL457Cloud = function(image) {
var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
// If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
// or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
              .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
              .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
// Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());

// remove pixels where the blue reflectance is greater than 0.2
var mask3 = image.select('B1').gt(2000);
return 
image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2)
.updateMask(mask3.not())
          .copyProperties(image)
          .copyProperties(image, 
["system:time_start",'system:time_end','system:footprint']);
};


var l4_sr = 
ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT04/C01/T1_SR').map(rmL457Cloud)
        .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUD_COVER',5))//云量过滤;
        

//MNDWI>NDVI
function calcWater(image) {
var MNDWI = image.select("MNDWI");
var NDVI = image.select("NDVI");
var EVI = image.select("EVI");
var water = EVI.lt(0.1)
             .and(MNDWI.gt(NDVI)//MNDWI>NDVI
             .or(MNDWI.gt(EVI)));
return image.addBands(water.rename("water"));
}
//Landsat-4处理方法
var Landsat4 = {
/*Landsat SR数据需要缩放，比例是 0.0001*/
scaleImage: function(image) {
var time_start = image.get("system:time_start");
image = image.select(["B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B7"]);
image = image.divide(10000);
image = image.set("system:time_start", time_start);
return image;
},

/* SR数据去云*/
srCloudMask: function(image) {
var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
var snowBitMask = (1 << 4);
var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
var mask1 = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0)
              .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(snowBitMask).eq(0))
              .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0));
var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
return image.updateMask(mask1.and(mask2));
},

 //NDVI
 NDVI: function(image) {
  return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(["B4", "B3"])
                             .rename("NDVI"));
 },

 //MNDWI
 MNDWI: function(image) {
  return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(["B2", "B5"])
                             .rename("MNDWI"));
 },

 // EVI
 EVI: function(image) {
 var evi = image.expression("EVI = 2.5 * (NIR - R) / (NIR + 6*R -7.5*B + 1)", {
  NIR: image.select("B4"),
  R: image.select("B3"),
  B: image.select("B1")
});
return image.addBands(evi);
},
/*获取Landsat4的SR数据*/
getL4SRCollection : function(startDate, endDate, region) {
var dataset = l4_sr.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                  .filterBounds(region)
                  .map(Landsat4.srCloudMask)
                  .map(Landsat4.scaleImage)
                  .map(Landsat4.NDVI)
                  .map(Landsat4.MNDWI)
                  .map(Landsat4.EVI)
                  .map(calcWater)
                  .select("water");
 return dataset;
 }
};

//export
function exportImageToDrive(image, key, region) {
Export.image.toDrive({
image: image, 
description: "Drive-"+key,
fileNamePrefix: key, 
region: region,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e13
});
}

//生成每一年的水体 and输出像元值 
function processYearWaterImage(year, region) {
var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1);
var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year+1, 1, 1);
var l4Water = Landsat4.getL4SRCollection(startDate, endDate, region);
var waterImgs = l4Water
/*计算水体的频率*/
var waterImg = waterImgs.sum()
                      .divide(waterImgs.count())
                      .clip(region);
var key = "landsatWater-"+year;
Map.addLayer(waterImg, {min:0,max:1,palette:['000000','blue']}, "water"+key, true);
exportImageToDrive(waterImg, key, region);
print('waterImgs_'+year,waterImgs);
var stats2 = waterImg.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: roi,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1E13
  });
  print(stats2,year)

  }
  //循环导出所有的水体
  function main() {
  //Map.addLayer(roi.style({color: "ffff00", fillColor: "00000000"}), {}, "roi");
  //开始年份和结束年份
  var startYear = 1982;
 var endYear = 1987;
 for (var year=startYear; year<=endYear; year++) {
processYearWaterImage(year, roi);
}
}

main();
```

When trying to extract water, I find my image collection has 0 elements. what can be the reason？ where do I need to modify？

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your collection is empty because there is no Landsat 4 imagery for your region and date range:

```
var region = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[
  [112.01637668750301, 30.256437069990916],
  [112.01637668750301, 29.3316436760148],
  [113.72749729297176, 29.3316436760148],
  [113.72749729297176, 30.256437069990916]
]])

var year = 1987
var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1)
var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year + 1, 1, 1)
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT04/C01/T1_SR')
var inRegion = collection
  .filterBounds(region)
var inDateRange = collection
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
var inRegionAndDateRange = collection
  .filterBounds(region)
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
print(
  'collection',
  collection.size(), 
  '\ninRegion',
  inRegion.size(),
  '\ninDateRange',
  inDateRange.size(),
  '\ninRegionAndDateRange',
  inRegionAndDateRange.size()
)

Map.addLayer(region)
Map.centerObject(region)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0139329541bac628a20cf69ecc08c34a

This ouputs:

```
collection
22374

inRegion
5

inDateRange
1267

inRegionAndDateRange
0
```